# I have tried to trigger the testng suite with pom.xml file but it showing an error showing as below

Tags: eclipse, maven, testng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfxw8.png)

I'm learning selenium but this problem i couldn't solve any one kindly ans if you know how to solve

Comment: You haven't actually explained what you're doing to the point where someone could reproduce the problem and help you get past it. Start by putting the error message here *in* *text* rather than an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fix the following issues:

1. When running from within eclipse, you seem to be choosing a maven profile named `TestNg` (check in your run configurations if you are using `-P TestNg` and if yes remove it), which doesn't exist in your pom file (your pom file should have an entry called `<profiles>` if you have defined profiles). So you need to update your run configuration.
2. Your pom file is missing a `<dependency>` entry for TestNG. So you are encountering classpath related errors.

Add the following inside `<dependencies>`

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

That should fix both your problems.